# Post comment to Wordpress blog from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, wordpress

I used a code to post a comment to a wordpress blog from the following question:

[Post comment to WordPress Blog from iPhone programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564276/post-comment-to-wordpress-blog-from-iphone-programmatically)

I made a few modifications to get text from UITextFields:

```
- (IBAction)postComment:(id)sender {
    NSString *post_url = @"http://movilarena.com/wp-comments-post.php";
    NSString *post_content = @"comment_post_ID=%@&comment_parent=%@&author=%@&email=%@&comment=%@";

    NSString *post_str = [NSString stringWithFormat:post_content, @"1", @"0", self.txtName.text, self.txtEmail.text, self.txtComment.text];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[post_str UTF8String] length:[post_str length]];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:post_url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [req setHTTPBody:data];

    //Synchronous
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *ret = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *retString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[ret bytes]];
    NSLog(@"%@",retString);
}
```

My problem is that the sendSynchronousRequest returns an error:

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,
>   address=0x0). The process has been returned to the state before
>   execution.

I will appreciate any suggestions to identify what's wrong here. I use XCode 4.5.2 and run the code on an iPhone 4S with iOS 6.0.1

Comment: i tried to use your code and i got this error "Sorry, this comment could not be posted." Can you please help me

Comment: Did you see my own answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself. The field `comment_post_ID` should be the ID of the post I am trying to reply.

```
NSString *post_content = @"comment_post_ID=%d&comment_parent=%@&author=%@&email=%@&comment=%@";

NSString *post_str = [NSString stringWithFormat:post_content, self.postID, @"0", self.txtName.text, self.txtEmail.text, self.txtComment.text];
```